# Buddypress, "$bp->current_component" returns empty string

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm new to buddypress. I've just referred ['John James Jacoby'](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/make-your-own-custom-buddypress-page/) to create a custom page dynamically without going into the admin panel.

I can get the current component name in default buddypress pages using the below code:

```
global $bp;
var_dump($bp->current_action);
```

But the problem I face here is that when I try create a new page as mentioned in the 'John James Jacoby', I get 404 error. 
I can't figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance..